# How to find the IP of a network printer from command line

Tags: windows, ip, printer

How can I ping (from command prompt) a printer without knowing it's IP.
How can I find the printer IP in the command prompt?

Comment: There is no native feature to find the IP address of a printer on the network. Your going to have to do some type of network scan. Even if you do it manually you’re going to have to check every IP on the network until you find it. If the printer is installed on the computer then you can certainly get details about it. Typically if you’re looking for a printer’s IP address you’ll go to the DHCP server, the printer’s control panel, or another computer on the network that has it installed.

Comment: Also, if you have control of your network, assign the printer an IP address in the DHCP control panel (typically on your router) - then you get to know its IP.  (Also you may want to advise your OS, as the answer may be different between OS types)

Comment: If you know the MAC address of the printer you can run `arp -a` and match the MAC address to the IP address

Comment: @DavidPostil that will only work, I believe, if the MAC address is in the ARP table, and if the printer has not been used for a while it won't exist there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For our IPP printer (EPSON ET_16650 Series), WMIC and PowerShell don't know the hostname, just the portname - which has the original IP address baked in. Now that the address has changed, the actual IP seems only to be found under the registry key for the port:

```
HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port\Ports\IP_192.168.0.11
```

which has a String value with the current IP:

```
HostName: 192.168.101.11
```

(The IPAddress String value there is empty.)

So at least in our case, the command line approach would be to find the port name, e.g. with PowerShell manually:

```
get-printer | select name, portname

name                                    portname
----                                    --------
Microsoft XPS Document Writer           PORTPROMPT:
EPSON ET-16650 Series                   IP_192.168.0.11

$portname = "IP_192.168.0.11"
```

or if you know the exact name of the printer in Windows, you can do it programmatically:

```
$portname = (get-printer "EPSON ET-16650 Series" | select portname).portname
```

You can then use that $portname to get the actual IP:

```
$basekey  = "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port\Ports\"
$key      = $basekey + $portname
$value    = "HostName"
(Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name $value).$value

192.168.101.11
```

Comment: I have an IPP printer configured, but the registry folder you specify (`\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port\Ports\`) doesn't have any subfolders or printer-specific keys, just some timeout keys. Despite its DriverName being `Microsoft IPP Class Driver`, its PortName has the `WSD` prefix.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the printer mapped on the Windows PC, there are various powershell or WMI commands to run:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/77344a1d-4d0a-40bb-a8d8-75516ba12b0a/get-printer-names-ip-addresses-and-drivers-from-a-computer-using-wmi?forum=ITCG

```
get-wmiobject win32_printer | select name

get-wmiobject win32_tcpipprinterport | select hostaddress
```

Depending on your printer and drivers, this may not have the IP address and you'll have to query WMI.

```
wmic printer get DriverName, Name, Portname
```

If it's an HP laser network printer, you may be connecting to port 9100, and netstat will show active network connections from powershell:

```
netstat -an | grep 9100
```

Comment: "get-wmiobject win32_tcpipprinterport | select hostaddress" returns nothing

Comment: "wmic printer get PortName" returns:
PortName
nul:
nul:
pdfcmon
PORTPROMPT:
PORTPROMPT:
SHRFAX:
pdfcmon

Answer (score 3):

Most of the network printers uses IPv4.
Open command prompt and run,
`ipconfig` to know  your IP address, then check your address resolution protocols to see connected devices by running `arp -a` on command prompt window.
If you are still in doubt download nmap from [here](https://nmap.org/download.html) and scan your network.

Comment: "arp -a" helps in a way, at least i can guess the right IP

Answer (score 1):

If your command line is PowerShell:

If the printer port is a TCPIPPrinterPort you can use this command:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort
```

And get the host address.

If the printer port is a WSD Port, you can check each item of:

```
HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\DAFWSDProvider\
```

to retrieve the IP address.
Here [at GitHUB is a script to do this](https://github.com/UserL4mbda/GetPrinterIP/blob/master/GetPrinterIP.ps1).

Comment: "Get-WmiObject Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort" returns nothing

Comment: @Remus do you have on your system a printer installed with a TCPIP port ?  You can check all your PrinterPort with `Get-PrinterPort`  The PortMonitor for a TCPIP port is "TCPMON.DLL"

Comment: yes, the printer is installed on a printserver, but I add it via add printer / "The printer that I want isn’t listed" / "Add a printer using TCP/IP address" and sometimes when I want to check the printer for the IP there is a WDS.... driver instead

Comment: @Remus If the printer has a WDS port you can find its IP in the registry there: `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\DAFWSDProvider\` or you can use this script [https://github.com/UserL4mbda/GetPrinterIP/blob/master/GetPrinterIP.ps1]

Answer (score 0):

You could run a batch file to loop through the addresses, ping each for half a second and move on. That should work fine as long as you only have one or a couple of subnets. If your network is very complicated it may take a very long time. Here's a sample script:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a counter=0
:start
set /a counter+=1
ping -n 1 192.168.0.!counter! > devices.txt
if %counter%=255 goto finish
goto start
:finish
```

Comment: ping is a bad solution because we dont know that icmp is enabled, nor dies tbe printer "jump out". You would be better off ysing a tool like nmap and scan for port tcp 630 and/or 631 and/or 9100 - all of these represent different protocols most printers listen on.